# Optional value on optional parameter

Tags: node.js, docopt

```
Usage:
  generate [<input>] [(--output <file> | --stdout)] [--validate]
  generate <input> --output <file> [--watch <dir>] [--validate]

Options:
  <input>                        Input file
  -o <file>, --output <file>     Send output to a file
  --stdout                       Send to standard out
  -v, --validate                 Validate
  --watch <dir>                  Watch a directory [default: .]
  -h, --help                     Help
```

In the second usage scenario, I’d like to make the `--watch` parameter optional. However, if employed, I’d also like to make its value optional, falling back to the default if not specified. I would have thought something like

```
[--watch [<dir>]]
```

would work. However, that gives me an `Unmatched '('` error. For example,

```
../generate dummy-table.html --output dummy.html --watch
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Node.js: 5.1.0
docopt: 0.6.2